# Correlation for each pair of genres

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 columns (same as below). I want to find the **Correlation Matrix** among each pair of genre which are represented by ID in second column and visualize them. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

```
UserID,Genre
1,2
1,5
1,9
2,2
2,3
3,4
3,4
3,19
3,6
3,7
```

Comment: Each ID has a different number of values? How do you want to calculate correlation?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, thanks for replying.  Yes, they do not have the same number. The original dataset that I have has 7 columns. UserID(int), Age, Gender, ItemID(int), RecommendationID(int), Timestamp,Genre(int) . Thanks again

Comment: You cannot compute a *correlation matrix*, but you can compute an [intraclass correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation), see e.g. function `ICC` in the library `psy`.